# Relation between eignenvalues of $A$, $B$ and $A+B$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to know if there is any relation between eigenvalues of $A$, $B$ and $A+B$, can we say anything about eignevalues of $A+B$ being real/complex, given that eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are real/complex? $A$ and $B$ need not be symmetric matrices/diagonal matrices. The entries of $A$ and $B$ and even $A+B$ are $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: You can say something when an eigenvector of A is also an eigenvector of B and the other way around.

Comment: Do the Eigenvalues of the $\{0,1\}$ matrices have special properties ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, no, I just gave that information thinking that it might help in answering the question!

Comment: You should check this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, is there any link missing in the comment?

Comment: No. "This" denotes "Do the Eigenvalues of the ${0,1}$ matrices have special properties ?"

Comment: There are $2\times2$ matrices $A,B$ meeting your criteria such that both $A,B$ have $0$ as their only eigenvalue, whereas $A+B$ has eigenvalues $\pm i$. So it's hard to imagine any general statement without further qualifications.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, can you give me a precise example? I thought there does not exist a $2 \times 2$ matrix with 0,1 entries and complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @mathcurious: Ah sorry, I must have seen a $-$ sign there. Indeed the eigenvalues of all such matrices are real. I'll think about it a bit more.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Do let me know if you come up or come across anything related.

Comment: Well here's a $4\times 4$ binary matrix with very complex eigenvalues: https://mathoverflow.net/a/99847/27465, and I think it can be written as a sum of two matrices which each have very simple eigenvalues.